# Asynchronous Javascript loading different behaviour

Tags: asynchronous, extjs, dom-events, unobtrusive-javascript

I am developing a widget, and am using extJS framework (along with stomp,orbited servers). It requires 5 different Javascript files. To avoid impacting load time for users, I am trying to load them asynchronously.

Through some callback stacks, I have managed to asynchronously load them in order they are required.

However, the widget does not work at all in the asynchronous case. I then copied the "modified" resultant HTML DOM from Chrome's developer tools, and created a static HTML file.

The static file works. I am printing few alerts when different JS files are loaded in both cases. The order of these alerts is the same.

How do I detect and fix the error. Stumped after lot of debugging.

(Link removed as they were on production server. Managed to detect the issue and find a workaround - please see answer below - keeping for anyone's reference).

Comment: the question is not clear enough for me, how are you loading the files?

Comment: Please view source for final.php. It sources single Js file embedd.js. This script loads 5 required JS files in sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Ext.onReady  is called as soon as document is ready, which is BEFORE any other scripts are loaded asynchronously.

Thus, the initialization code was not getting called. I manage to work it around by calling Ext.each("dummy args", initialization_function, this)  in the last javascript that is loaded. This made things work for me.